# Maximum number of background processes running spark-shell

Tags: bash, shell, apache-spark

I'm launching around 100 background processes in bash using a script and waiting for them to finish using -

```
declare -a pid
for i in {0..99}; do 
  bash run.sh 1>/dev/null 2>&1 &
  pid[$i]=$!
done

for i in {0..99}; do 
  wait ${ARRAY[$i]}
done
```

In run.sh, I'm running spark-shell. The script is crashing the system. Is it because of some limit on the number of background processes? Do these processes consume a lot of resources?

Comment: Discarding error messages and then asking for our help to figure out what's wrong is a waste of your own time as well as ours.

Answer (score 0):

I made one small change and it runs fine on bash 4.3.42(1)

```
#! /bin/bash
declare -a pid
for i in {0..99}; do 
  bash run.sh 1>/dev/null 2>&1 &
  pid[$i]=$!
done

for i in {0..99}; do 
  wait ${pid[i]}
done
```

I changed ${ARRAY[$i]} to ${pid[i]} , I'm not sure if that was a mistake copying to the question or if it's in the original script.

Worth noting that you also don't need the $ inside the square brackets for the array.

Comment: i copied it wrongly. i am able to run the script, but it crashes the system for spark-shell. i guess spark-shell takes a lot of resources

Comment: To start the troubleshooting process, have you tried monitoring system resources and launching only a few backgrounds tasks?

Comment: I was running this on azure. The cluster is down currently, i will do the troubleshooting once it's up